# Dictionary fetch all keys and use them as Array

Tags: swift, dictionary

I use method `.keys` from the `Dictionary` to fetch all keys that are in the dictionary and work with them like `Array`.

Problem when i fetch it `.keys` it returns `LazyMapCollection` how i can convert it to `Array` of keys.

Precondition:

User is structure with funds not nil dictionary `[String:String]`.

```
let keys = user.funds?.keys
```

How should i convert keys to be `Array`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe using `map` will help:

```
let dictionary: [String:String] = [:]
let keys: [String] = dictionary.map({ $0.key })
```

Don't like `map`? Go this way:

```
let dictionary: [String:String] = [:]
let keys: Array<String> = Array<String>(dictionary.keys)
```

Comment: I know this but how i can do this with help of .keys

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk updated the answer

Comment: Thx for the response

Comment: Great answer. I wanted something other then a for loop and I used the 2nd way (no map). I like it better then all the answers in the link to “this question already has an answer here”